# Probability distribution function of $ A\cdot \left(\sum X_i\right)^2 + B \sum X_i^2 $

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, numerical-methods, random-variables

Let $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed real-valued random variables. The PDF of each of these variables is given by $f(x)$. I need the PDF of a random variable $$ A\cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2 + B \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2, $$
where $A$ and $B$ are some real coefficients. Is there any way to calculate this PDF analytically? The main problem for me is that even if the PDFs of $\left(\sum X_i\right)^2$ and $\sum X_i^2$ are known, it's not easy to obtain the formula for PDF of a linear combination of these two terms, because they are not independent. If it's not possible to obtain the PDF analytically, are there any efficient numerical algorithms to approximate it?

Comment: Whether one can find the pdf analytically or numerically depends of $f(x)$.  Do you have a specific $f$ in mind?

Comment: Yes, let's assume that $f(x)$ is a linear combination of two normal distributions with different mean values ($\mu$ and $-\mu$), i.e. $f(x) = C \exp \left(- \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \right) +  D \exp \left(- \frac{(x+\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \right)$.